# Compiling more than one Elm project in Webpack

Tags: webpack, phoenix-framework, elm

I'm running a Phoenix server, where the Webpack config file looks like this in parts:

```
entry: {
  'elm-db': './elm-db/src/Main.elm',
  'elm-ledger': './elm-ledger/src/Main.elm',
},
output: {
  filename: '[name].js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js'),
  publicPath: '/js/',
},

module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.elm$/,
      exclude: [/elm-stuff/, /node_modules/],
      use: {
        loader: 'elm-webpack-loader',
        options: {
          cwd: path.resolve(__dirname, 'elm-db'),
          debug: options.mode === "development",
          optimize: options.mode === "production",
        },
      },
    },
  ]
},
```

I have two Elm projects, `elm-db` and `elm-ledger`. I've managed to add `elm-db` correctly to the config file, and it compiles the project just fine. However, I keep failing to add "elm-ledger" as well. The code above produces a correct `elm-db.js` file, but compiling `elm-ledger.js` returns errors, probably because I can't make a correct `cwd` field. I can't find any documentation on the configuration of `cwd`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "fail to add elm-ledger"? Are any files compiled/output for `elm-ledger` at all? Do you see any indication that webpack's picking it up in the log output? At a glance, it looks like you may have an issue with configuring the `cwd` for `elm-webpack-loader` to always point to `elm-db`, that should probably be different per entrypoint.

Comment: _Can you clarify what you mean by "fail to add elm-ledger"?_

The code above produces a correct "elm-db.js" file, but compiling "elm-ledger.js" returns errors, probably because I can't make a correct "cwd" field.

_it looks like you may have an issue with configuring the cwd for elm-webpack-loader to always point to elm-db, that should probably be different per entrypoint._

Yes, but I don't know how to correct it. I can't find any documentation on the configuration of "cwd".

Comment: The documentation for `elm-webpack-loader#cwd` can be found in the project's repo [here](https://github.com/elm-community/elm-webpack-loader#cwd-default-null-recommended). From the project's provided examples, it doesn't appear that building multiple elm files is supported, so there are two things you could try: 1) move `elm-db` and `elm-ledger` into a single project as separate [modules](https://guide.elm-lang.org/webapps/modules.html), then just use that project as the entrypoint, or 2) (not recommended) create a second webpack process for each and run them in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps or not but we are doing it with the old version of
`"elm-webpack-loader": "^6.0.1"` (The latest version may have different configurations)

```js
const elmPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/.bin/elm');
const srcPaths = [
  path.resolve(__dirname, './app1'),
  path.resolve(__dirname, './app2'),
  path.resolve(__dirname, './app3'),
];

const elmRules = srcPaths.map(featurePath => ({
  test: new RegExp(`^${featurePath}.*elm$`),
  include: featurePath,
  exclude: [/elm-stuff/, /node_modules/],
  use: [
    {
      loader: require.resolve('elm-webpack-loader'),
      options: {
        pathToElm: elmPath,
        cwd: featurePath,
        // other options
      },
    },
  ],
}));
```

Then you spread that `...elmRules` in Webpack config rules